# Behavior of C++ array created in function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I wrote this simple function to learn about arrays in C++ (I am using CERN's ROOT as a C++ compiler):

```
int** vec() {
  int n = 2;
  int m = 3;

  int *pointer[m];                                                                                                                              

  for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    pointer[i] = new int[n];
  }

  for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
      pointer[i][j] = -1;
    }
  }

  return pointer;
}
```

After compiling the code, which I have saved as test.C, I create two pointers to two-arrays in what seems to me an identical manner, but with different results. The first was works exactly as I expected both methods to work:

```
root [0] .L test.C+
root [1] 
root [1] int** mat1;
root [2] int** mat2;
root [3] mat1 = vec();
root [4] mat2 = vec();
root [5] mat1[0][0]
(int)(-1)
root [6] mat2[0][0]
(int)(-1)
```

Okay, nothing surprising there. But if I do all the stuff with mat1 before getting to mat2, I get the following very different result:

```
root [0] .L test.C+
root [1] 
root [1] int** mat1;
root [2] mat1 = vec();
root [3] mat1[0][0]
(int)(-460363344)
root [4] 
root [4] int** mat2;
root [5] mat2 = vec();
root [6] mat2[0][0]
(int)(-1)
```

In this case, it appears that my function has not worked as far as mat1 is concerned. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: You're returning a local variable address (`pointer`), which invokes undefined behavior upon reference on the caller-side. The impending memory leaks are pure bonus points.

Comment: Do you see any **warnings** when you compile this code?

Comment: The local variable is destroyed when the function exits and is no longer available (undefined behavior).  Try using a static array or a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: @DrewDormann No warnings

Comment: @user3757134 then the real problem is that you are compiling with warnings disabled.  :)  I'm not familiar with CERN'S ROOT, but I'm wary of a compiler that compiles that without warning you that your code returns a pointer to a local array.

Comment: This code cannot be possibly compiled as a compliant C++ code. C++ language does not support array declarations with sizes represented by non-constants (like `int *pointer[m]`) in your case. A feature like that exists in C, but not in C++. Even if your compiler accepts it (as a non-standard extension), the problem, as others have already noted, is that you are returning a pointer to a local array.

Comment: @AndreyT but g++ *does* support it via non-standard extension (unfortunately).

Comment: @AndreyT Why does declaring and calling my pointers in different orders change the behavior? I would expect both orders to behave identically, problems with my pointer declaration or not.

Comment: @user3757134: You are reading invalid memory, which is generally filled with random garbage. One thing about random garbage is that it is *random*. It can change for any reason or without a reason. There's nothing unusual in the fact that "calling your pointers in different orders" changes that random garbage (whatever you mean by "calling pointers").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following problems:

**Problem 1**

```
int *pointer[m];
```

is not legal C++ code.

**Problem 2**

When you execute

```
return pointer;
```

you are returning a pointer to memory that is not valid after the function returns.

The simple fix is to replace the line

```
int *pointer[m];
```

by

```
int ** pointer =  new int*[m];
```

Comment: But now you've got a new problem... deleting that memory (pun intended). You should probably use a vector instead.

Comment: @Cogwheel I would, but a vector of vectors doesn't work in ROOT

Comment: A vector of pointers should work. `&vec[0]` would be equivalent to the int** you're returning now. Possibly even a vector of unique_ptrs, and then you wouldn't even have to manually manage the elements' deletion.

Comment: Thanks, I might do that. For my purposes, I am only doing int** pointer = vec() inside of a for loop, which I think will take care of memory things, but I don't really know.